# Omniauth + Devise + Rails 4: strategy.rb:143:in `initialize': Received wrong number of arguments. ["google_apps"] (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I'm upgrading my Rails app from 3.1.3 to 4.0.2. In order to do that I need to upgrade devise and omniauth too.

I had these gems in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'devise', '1.4.9'
gem 'omniauth', '0.3.2'
gem 'oa-openid'
```

I changed them to:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'oa-openid'
```

When I start my rails server I get this traceback.

> /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:143:in`initialize': Received wrong number of arguments. ["google_apps"] (ArgumentError)
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/oa-openid-0.3.2/lib/omniauth/strategies/open_id.rb:39:in`initialize'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/oa-openid-0.3.2/lib/omniauth/strategies/google_apps.rb:8:in `initialize'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in`new'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:118:in`block in build'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:118:in `each'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:118:in`inject'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:118:in `build'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:495:in`app'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:34:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in`block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in`block in each_strongly_connected_component'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in`each_strongly_connected_component'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
>       from /Users/andy/heroku/selfiemarket/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in`require'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in`load_dependency'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
>       from /Users/andy/heroku/selfiemarket/config.ru:3:in`block in '
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`initialize'
>       from /Users/andy/heroku/selfiemarket/config.ru:in `new'
>       from /Users/andy/heroku/selfiemarket/config.ru:in`'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`new_from_string'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in`build_app_and_options_from_config'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in`app'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in`start'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in`tap'
>       from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
>       from script/rails:6:in`require'
>       from script/rails:6:in `'

In `config/initiailizers/devise.rb` I had this line:

```
config.omniauth :google_apps, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp'), :domain => 'gmail.com'
```

I changed it to:

```
config.omniauth :google_apps, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :domain => 'gmail.com'
```

I still get the error.

I originally used this example project to setup my Omniauth and Devise app https://github.com/holden/devise-omniauth-example

Comment: Did you fix it? Care to post your solution?

Comment: Justin or Andy, could you post your solution. I was working on updating Rails 3.0 app to version 3.2 and encountered the same error. I solved it by switching from oa-openid gem to omniauth-google-apps

Comment: Did anyone solve that?